# SELECT the last 15 downloads by a user, but with unique filenames

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, distinct

mySQL DB. Its a download log table. A user can download the same file more than once.

I want to select the last 15 unique file downloads by a given user.

So if a users last X downloads are:

```
UserA, file001, 14.52
UserA, file006, 14.49
UserA, file001, 14.43-Duplicate
```

I want to select the last x downloads  but where the filename is unique, so:

```
UserA, file001, 14.52
UserA, file006, 14.49
```

I have the code to select the last 15 downloads, but i don't know how to apply a group by/distinct to **JUST** the  fileName column:

```
SELECT `fileName`,`time` FROM `downloads`
WHERE `userName` = 'userA' 
ORDER BY `time` DESC
LIMIT 15
```

So how do i make sure only unique filenames are returned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT `fileName`,MAX(`time`) 
FROM `downloads`
WHERE `userName` = 'userA' 
GROUP BY `fileName`
ORDER BY MAX(`time`) DESC
LIMIT 15
```

A `GROUP BY` on `fileName` with [`MAX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) on time (to get the last time, to get the first time use [`MIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min)) should suffice.

Comment: I guess you mean `SELECT fileName,MAX(time) AS maxtime` and `ORDER BY maxtime`.

Answer (score 0):

do you care about the time?

Otherwise, you could try

```
SELECT `fileName`,`time` FROM `downloads`
WHERE `userName` = 'userA' 
GROUP BY `fileName`
ORDER BY `time` DESC
LIMIT 15
```

Comment: This is not correct. If a `filename` has 2 or more downloads, it will have 2 or more different times associated with it. Which one do you think that MySQL will choose?

Comment: I just tried this and it works. As I say in the beginning of my post, if you don't care about the time, you will get a list with unique double downloads, no? Ok you might get rid of the ORDER BY 'time' clause...

Comment: ***"It works in my machine"***: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/the-works-on-my-machine-certification-program.html

Comment: No, you just need to replace it with `ORDER BY MAX(time)` so for every `filename` the latest `time` is chosen and used for the ordering. See @cularis answer.

Comment: Lol for the blog post, but I still maintain that the code is not wrong. Whichever time it takes doesn't matter as long as the returned list is unique. I see now that the OP is interested in the "latest" information, in which case the MAX is required. I give you that, but in principle "without being interested in the WHEN" the SQL does work.

Comment: Your code does work but doesn't return what the OP asked, that's what I mean. It does group by filename, chooses a more or less random time if the filename has duplicates, then orders by that time and chooses the last 15. It just may work in your case because you have very few rows in the table, because the optimizer chooses to use an index that finds first the row with maximum time. WHat I mean is that your code does not work in general according to what the OP was asking.

Comment: Yes I agree, and by my code works I meant it does return a list a unique list, disregarding time and the SQL does not blow up. Slight confusion and sorry for that :)